# Java: sound transportation issues

Tags: java, audio, format, system, wav

I have a `SoundManager` class and a `Sound` class set up so that I can play sounds from anywhere in my code. My issue is that when at home, the sound clips play fine (after converting them to the correct audio form of `.wav`). However, at school, the program crashes, saying the audio format is not supported. Is there a way I can get the audio to run on any system, regardless of the java version?

Thanks

Comment: Wav should always be supported, but not necessarily all sample rates etc. What is the exactly exception message you get?

Comment: @greg-449 unsure of the exact message as I'm not currently at school, but the audio format of my `.wav`'s are: `PCM_SIGNED 44100.0 Hz, 16 bit, stereo, 4 bytes/frame, little-endian`, which it says isn't supported at school

Comment: That looks like normal CD quality audio. Possibly the system doesn't support 'little-endian' or something like that. You would have to look at the formats supported by the output SourceDataLine to see if that matches a supported format.

Comment: @greg-449 how would i go about viewing those outputs?

Comment: For a `Mixer` call `mixer.getSourceLineInfo()` to get an array of `Line.Info`. if the `Line.Info` is an instance of `DataLine.Info` you can then call `getFormats()` to get an array of supported audio formats.

Comment: @greg-449 example code of this? Post as an answer :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can see the formats that the Java Sounds API supports on a machine using something like:

```
public static void displayMixerInfo()
{
  Mixer.Info [] mixersInfo = AudioSystem.getMixerInfo();

  for (Mixer.Info mixerInfo : mixersInfo)
   {
     System.out.println("Mixer: " + mixerInfo.getName());

     Mixer mixer = AudioSystem.getMixer(mixerInfo);

     Line.Info [] sourceLineInfo = mixer.getSourceLineInfo();
     for (Line.Info info : sourceLineInfo)
      {
        showLineInfo(info);
      }

     Line.Info [] targetLineInfo = mixer.getTargetLineInfo();
     for (Line.Info info : targetLineInfo)
      {
        showLineInfo(info);
      }
   }
}


private static void showLineInfo(Line.Info lineInfo)
{
  System.out.println("  " + lineInfo.toString());

  if (lineInfo instanceof DataLine.Info)
   {
     DataLine.Info dataLineInfo = (DataLine.Info)lineInfo;

     AudioFormat [] formats = dataLineInfo.getFormats();
     for (AudioFormat format : formats)
      {
        System.out.println("    " + format.toString());
      }
   }
}
```

On my Mac this displays:

```
Mixer: Default Audio Device
  interface SourceDataLine supporting 14 audio formats, and buffers of at least 32 bytes
    PCM_UNSIGNED unknown sample rate, 8 bit, mono, 1 bytes/frame, 
    PCM_SIGNED unknown sample rate, 8 bit, mono, 1 bytes/frame, 
    PCM_SIGNED unknown sample rate, 16 bit, mono, 2 bytes/frame, little-endian
    PCM_SIGNED unknown sample rate, 16 bit, mono, 2 bytes/frame, big-endian
    PCM_SIGNED unknown sample rate, 24 bit, mono, 3 bytes/frame, little-endian
    PCM_SIGNED unknown sample rate, 24 bit, mono, 3 bytes/frame, big-endian
    PCM_UNSIGNED unknown sample rate, 8 bit, stereo, 2 bytes/frame, 
    PCM_SIGNED unknown sample rate, 8 bit, stereo, 2 bytes/frame, 
    PCM_SIGNED unknown sample rate, 16 bit, stereo, 4 bytes/frame, little-endian
    PCM_SIGNED unknown sample rate, 16 bit, stereo, 4 bytes/frame, big-endian
    PCM_SIGNED unknown sample rate, 24 bit, stereo, 6 bytes/frame, little-endian
    PCM_SIGNED unknown sample rate, 24 bit, stereo, 6 bytes/frame, big-endian
    PCM_SIGNED 44100.0 Hz, 16 bit, stereo, 4 bytes/frame, little-endian
    PCM_SIGNED 44100.0 Hz, 16 bit, stereo, 4 bytes/frame, big-endian
  interface Clip supporting 14 audio formats, and buffers of at least 32 bytes
    PCM_UNSIGNED unknown sample rate, 8 bit, mono, 1 bytes/frame, 
    PCM_SIGNED unknown sample rate, 8 bit, mono, 1 bytes/frame, 
    PCM_SIGNED unknown sample rate, 16 bit, mono, 2 bytes/frame, little-endian
    PCM_SIGNED unknown sample rate, 16 bit, mono, 2 bytes/frame, big-endian
    PCM_SIGNED unknown sample rate, 24 bit, mono, 3 bytes/frame, little-endian
    PCM_SIGNED unknown sample rate, 24 bit, mono, 3 bytes/frame, big-endian
    PCM_UNSIGNED unknown sample rate, 8 bit, stereo, 2 bytes/frame, 
    PCM_SIGNED unknown sample rate, 8 bit, stereo, 2 bytes/frame, 
    PCM_SIGNED unknown sample rate, 16 bit, stereo, 4 bytes/frame, little-endian
    PCM_SIGNED unknown sample rate, 16 bit, stereo, 4 bytes/frame, big-endian
    PCM_SIGNED unknown sample rate, 24 bit, stereo, 6 bytes/frame, little-endian
    PCM_SIGNED unknown sample rate, 24 bit, stereo, 6 bytes/frame, big-endian
    PCM_SIGNED 44100.0 Hz, 16 bit, stereo, 4 bytes/frame, little-endian
    PCM_SIGNED 44100.0 Hz, 16 bit, stereo, 4 bytes/frame, big-endian
  interface TargetDataLine supporting 14 audio formats, and buffers of at least 32 bytes
    PCM_UNSIGNED unknown sample rate, 8 bit, mono, 1 bytes/frame, 
    PCM_SIGNED unknown sample rate, 8 bit, mono, 1 bytes/frame, 
    PCM_SIGNED unknown sample rate, 16 bit, mono, 2 bytes/frame, little-endian
    PCM_SIGNED unknown sample rate, 16 bit, mono, 2 bytes/frame, big-endian
    PCM_SIGNED unknown sample rate, 24 bit, mono, 3 bytes/frame, little-endian
    PCM_SIGNED unknown sample rate, 24 bit, mono, 3 bytes/frame, big-endian
    PCM_UNSIGNED unknown sample rate, 8 bit, stereo, 2 bytes/frame, 
    PCM_SIGNED unknown sample rate, 8 bit, stereo, 2 bytes/frame, 
    PCM_SIGNED unknown sample rate, 16 bit, stereo, 4 bytes/frame, little-endian
    PCM_SIGNED unknown sample rate, 16 bit, stereo, 4 bytes/frame, big-endian
    PCM_SIGNED unknown sample rate, 24 bit, stereo, 6 bytes/frame, little-endian
    PCM_SIGNED unknown sample rate, 24 bit, stereo, 6 bytes/frame, big-endian
    PCM_SIGNED 44100.0 Hz, 16 bit, stereo, 4 bytes/frame, little-endian
    PCM_SIGNED 44100.0 Hz, 16 bit, stereo, 4 bytes/frame, big-endian
Mixer: Built-in Microphone
  interface TargetDataLine supporting 14 audio formats, and buffers of at least 32 bytes
    PCM_UNSIGNED unknown sample rate, 8 bit, mono, 1 bytes/frame, 
    PCM_SIGNED unknown sample rate, 8 bit, mono, 1 bytes/frame, 
    PCM_SIGNED unknown sample rate, 16 bit, mono, 2 bytes/frame, little-endian
    PCM_SIGNED unknown sample rate, 16 bit, mono, 2 bytes/frame, big-endian
    PCM_SIGNED unknown sample rate, 24 bit, mono, 3 bytes/frame, little-endian
    PCM_SIGNED unknown sample rate, 24 bit, mono, 3 bytes/frame, big-endian
    PCM_UNSIGNED unknown sample rate, 8 bit, stereo, 2 bytes/frame, 
    PCM_SIGNED unknown sample rate, 8 bit, stereo, 2 bytes/frame, 
    PCM_SIGNED unknown sample rate, 16 bit, stereo, 4 bytes/frame, little-endian
    PCM_SIGNED unknown sample rate, 16 bit, stereo, 4 bytes/frame, big-endian
    PCM_SIGNED unknown sample rate, 24 bit, stereo, 6 bytes/frame, little-endian
    PCM_SIGNED unknown sample rate, 24 bit, stereo, 6 bytes/frame, big-endian
    PCM_SIGNED 44100.0 Hz, 16 bit, stereo, 4 bytes/frame, little-endian
    PCM_SIGNED 44100.0 Hz, 16 bit, stereo, 4 bytes/frame, big-endian
Mixer: Built-in Output
  interface SourceDataLine supporting 14 audio formats, and buffers of at least 32 bytes
    PCM_UNSIGNED unknown sample rate, 8 bit, mono, 1 bytes/frame, 
    PCM_SIGNED unknown sample rate, 8 bit, mono, 1 bytes/frame, 
    PCM_SIGNED unknown sample rate, 16 bit, mono, 2 bytes/frame, little-endian
    PCM_SIGNED unknown sample rate, 16 bit, mono, 2 bytes/frame, big-endian
    PCM_SIGNED unknown sample rate, 24 bit, mono, 3 bytes/frame, little-endian
    PCM_SIGNED unknown sample rate, 24 bit, mono, 3 bytes/frame, big-endian
    PCM_UNSIGNED unknown sample rate, 8 bit, stereo, 2 bytes/frame, 
    PCM_SIGNED unknown sample rate, 8 bit, stereo, 2 bytes/frame, 
    PCM_SIGNED unknown sample rate, 16 bit, stereo, 4 bytes/frame, little-endian
    PCM_SIGNED unknown sample rate, 16 bit, stereo, 4 bytes/frame, big-endian
    PCM_SIGNED unknown sample rate, 24 bit, stereo, 6 bytes/frame, little-endian
    PCM_SIGNED unknown sample rate, 24 bit, stereo, 6 bytes/frame, big-endian
    PCM_SIGNED 44100.0 Hz, 16 bit, stereo, 4 bytes/frame, little-endian
    PCM_SIGNED 44100.0 Hz, 16 bit, stereo, 4 bytes/frame, big-endian
  interface Clip supporting 14 audio formats, and buffers of at least 32 bytes
    PCM_UNSIGNED unknown sample rate, 8 bit, mono, 1 bytes/frame, 
    PCM_SIGNED unknown sample rate, 8 bit, mono, 1 bytes/frame, 
    PCM_SIGNED unknown sample rate, 16 bit, mono, 2 bytes/frame, little-endian
    PCM_SIGNED unknown sample rate, 16 bit, mono, 2 bytes/frame, big-endian
    PCM_SIGNED unknown sample rate, 24 bit, mono, 3 bytes/frame, little-endian
    PCM_SIGNED unknown sample rate, 24 bit, mono, 3 bytes/frame, big-endian
    PCM_UNSIGNED unknown sample rate, 8 bit, stereo, 2 bytes/frame, 
    PCM_SIGNED unknown sample rate, 8 bit, stereo, 2 bytes/frame, 
    PCM_SIGNED unknown sample rate, 16 bit, stereo, 4 bytes/frame, little-endian
    PCM_SIGNED unknown sample rate, 16 bit, stereo, 4 bytes/frame, big-endian
    PCM_SIGNED unknown sample rate, 24 bit, stereo, 6 bytes/frame, little-endian
    PCM_SIGNED unknown sample rate, 24 bit, stereo, 6 bytes/frame, big-endian
    PCM_SIGNED 44100.0 Hz, 16 bit, stereo, 4 bytes/frame, little-endian
    PCM_SIGNED 44100.0 Hz, 16 bit, stereo, 4 bytes/frame, big-endian
Mixer: Port Built-in Microphone
  MICROPHONE source port
Mixer: Port Built-in Output
  HEADPHONE target port
```